# Uniformly continuous integral example

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Can someone, please, help me with an example of improper integral of some function
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x, y)dx,$$ $c \leq y \leq  d$, which is uniformly continuous on $c \leq y \leq  d$, but for which we cannot apply Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of uniform *convergence* of the improper integral? This is what the Weierstrass test is usually used to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $0\le y\le {1\over 2},$ let $f(x,0)=0$ and $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} -{y\over \log y}, & 0\le x\le {1\over y}\\
0, & x>{1\over y}
\end{cases}$$
for $0<y\le {1\over 2}.$ Then $$\int\limits_0^\infty f(x,0)\,dx=0,\quad \int\limits_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dx=-\int\limits_0^{1/y}{y\over \log y}\,dx =-{1\over \log y},\quad 0<y\le {1\over 2}$$
The function $$g(y):=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dy=\begin{cases}0 & y=0\\
-{1\over \log y} & 0<y\le {1\over 2}\end{cases}$$
is continuous, therefore uniformly continuous on $[0,{1\over 2}].$
Moreover for fixed $x\ge 2$ we have
$$\sup_{0\le y\le {1\over 2}}f(x,y)\ge f\left (x,{1\over x}\right )={1\over x\log x} $$
and the function $(x\log x)^{-1}$ is not integrable on $[2,\infty).$ Hence the $M$-test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, f(x,y)=1$. Then f is continuous and in particular uniformly continuous but you cannot dominate it with an integrale function.

Comment: What about $\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dx$ ? It seems infinite.

Comment: You didn't ask for it to be finite.

Comment: It was not me but nezudem. I took it for granted, as it was required that $\int f(x,y)\,dx$ was a contiunous function of $y.$